Validation Constraints: How to assert that a string has exact length 4
Here is my simplified class of my DTO which is filled by the Serializer:
<?php

namespace App\Api\Dto;

use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups as SerializerGroups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


#[OA\Schema()]
readonly class WorkHour implements DtoInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        #[OA\Property(description: 'House name', type: 'string')]
        #[Assert\Length(
            exactly: 4,
            exactMessage: 'House name is mandatory. Stringlength 4',
            groups: ['create', 'update']
        )]
        #[SerializerGroups(['view', 'create', 'update', 'collection'])]
        public string $sapHouseNumber
        ) {
    }
}

I am writing unit tests and try to fail the validation by sending an empty string for this value with creation. But the json is serialized and my DTO is created without any complaint.
Is the Assert correct? Should it work?
If yes, I have to search for the error elsewhere in my code.
What am I missing? Why is my validation not working?
It looks like the class Length is used, but not the class LengthValidator.
php8.2, Smyfony 6.4

Should it work? Try to debug

Is it ok that the normalizer and the payload in the Length constraint is null?

The error was, that I hadn't configured MapRequestPayload correctly in my Controller.
I will add the essential code here, for all others, who have a similar problem.
The Constraint was configured correctly.
I added in my Controller the following:
        Route(path: '', name: 'create', methods: ['POST'], format: 'json')]
    public function create(#[MapRequestPayload(
        acceptFormat: 'json',
        serializationContext: ['create'],
        validationGroups: ['create'],
        resolver: DtoArgumentResolver::class
    )] WorkHourDto $workHourDto): CreatedView
    {
        $workHourDto = $this->workHourService->create($workHourDto);

        return $this->created($workHourDto);
    }

DtoArgumentResolver being the class were I call the serialisation and Vaidation:
class DtoArgumentResolver implements ValueResolverInterface
{
    use LoggerTrait;

    private SerializerInterface $serializer;
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        ValidatorInterface $validator
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): bool
    {
        if (null === $argument->getType()) {
            return false;
        }

        return 1 === preg_match('/App\\\\Api\\\\Dto\\\\[a-zA-Z]*/', $argument->getType());
    }

    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): Generator
    {
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $class = $argument->getType();

        if (empty($data)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Request data is empty');
        }

        try {
            /** @var DtoInterface $dto */
            $dto = $this->serializer->deserialize($data, $class, 'json');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = sprintf('Object of class %s caanot be created with this data: %s', $class, $data);
            throw new ApiException(Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, $message, $e, [], 1056);
        }

        $groups = null;
        if ($request->attributes->has('_validation_group')) {
            $groups = $request->attributes->get('_validation_group')->getGroup();
        }

        // we need the id for all PUT methods
        if ('PUT' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $violations = $this->validator->validate(
                ['dto' => $dto, 'id' => $request->attributes->get('id')],
                null,
                $groups
            );
        } else {
            $violations = $this->validator->validate($dto, null, $groups);
        }

        if (count($violations) > 0) {
            throw ValidationException::fromViolationCollection($violations);
        }

        yield $dto;
    }
}


Well I don't know your usecase, but in your question you mention "serializing". If you serialize a DTO into JSON, the symfony serializer does not any kind of validation, since it is not its responsibility. The validation itself is performed by the Validator component and it can be manually invoked (see this).
If your usecase is validating a JSON request that you get to an endpoint and then deserializing this request into a DTO, it would be helpful if you shared a Controller, where you are doing this deserialization. Since Symfony 6.3 there is an attribute #[MapRequestPayload] (see this) that tells the framework to validate (and return 422 by default, if there are any invalid data against constraints), and you should get fully validated and populated DTO.
Beware that validating null is in fact not a responsibility of Length constraint, but it is validated either by NotNull or NotBlank constraint.
So please, improve a bit on your question, clarify the use case and provide additional info about your framework version (6.0 / 6.1 / 6.2 ....).

I guess you hit the spot! I am currently upgrading my project from symfony 5 to 6.4 and the way we did the conversion from json to the objects in our Api changed. I guess at least part of my problem is that I was missing denomalization. I will try if I can fix my problem.
P.S: no clue, why someone downvoted your well written answer.

Because this feels more like a long-stretched comment than an actual answer at this point

I also added now NotEmpty and NotBlank to the validators. Thank you for pointing that out .

With your hints I could solve the problem. #[MapRequestPayload] wasn't configured properly, so it never used the Validation and the DeNormalizer.
I will post my correct code as answer.

@CalamityJane Glad you could solve the issue with your code, hope you learned something new :) The NotBlank constraint is usually enough for 99% usecases. It even supports "optional non-empty" attributes by setting allowNull to true. And the jump from 5 to 6.4 is a huge one. Be sure to check out the new features, such as the #[Autowire] attribute, If you google "curated news symfony 6" you get a pretty cool compiled list of almost all important features and improvements.

I think the Length constraint doesn't have an exact option. Instead, you should use the min and max options if you want to enforce an exact length. You have to update your DTO class to use min and max options like following
public function __construct(
  #[OA\Property(description: 'House name', type: 'string')]
  #[Assert\Length(
    **min: 4,
    max: 4,
    minMessage: 'House name must be exactly 4 characters long.',
    maxMessage: 'House name must be exactly 4 characters long.',**
    groups: ['create', 'update']
  )]
  #[SerializerGroups(['view', 'create', 'update', 'collection'])]
  public string $sapHouseNumber
)

As well as be sure that you are triggering the validation manually in your unit test.

The Length constraint does have an option for an exact length, see the manual here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#exactly
